# Java linked List implementation won't add data

Tags: java, arrays, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I created my own linked list in java(code below) and I was trying to store DNA?RNA sequences from a text file in an array of a custom data type that contains the enum DNA/RNA, as well as a linked list containing the actual DNA sequence. I don't know if the characters are just not being inserted into the linked list or if there is a problem with my toString but the output only prints the position and enum type, not the sequence from the list. Code is below 
My node class

```
public class Node<E> {
    private Node<E> next;
    protected E data;

    Node(E data,Node<E> nextVal){
        this.data=data;
        next=nextVal;
    }
    Node(Node<E> nextVal){
        next=nextVal;
    }

    Node<E> Next(){
        return next;
    }
    Node<E>setNext(Node<E> nextVal){
        return next=nextVal;
    }
    E data(){
        return data;
    }
    E setData(E it){
        return data=it;
    }
}
```

My Linked List Class

```
    public class MyLinkedList<E> implements List<E>{
    private Node<E> head;
    private Node<E> tail;
    protected Node<E> curr;
    private int size;
    MyLinkedList(int size){
        this();
    }
    MyLinkedList(){
        curr=tail=head=new Node<E>(null);
        size=0;
    }
      @Override
      public void clear() {
        head.setNext(null);
        curr=tail=head=new Node<E>(null);
        size=0;
      }

      @Override
      public void insert(E item) {
        curr.setNext(new Node<E>(item, curr.Next()));
        if(tail==curr)
            tail=curr.Next();
        size++;

      }
      @Override
      public void append(E item) {
        tail=tail.setNext(new Node<E>(item, null));
        size++;
      }

      @Override
      public E remove() {
        if(curr.Next() ==null)
          return null;
        E item=curr.Next().data();
        if(tail==curr.Next())
            tail=curr;
        curr.setNext(curr.Next().Next());
        size--;
        return item;
    }

      @Override
      public void moveToStart() {
        curr =head;
      }

      @Override
      public void moveToEnd() {
        curr=tail;
      }

      @Override
      public void prev() {
        if(curr==head)
            return;
        Node<E> temp=head;
        while (temp.Next()!=curr)
            temp=temp.Next();
        curr=temp;

      }

      @Override
      public void next() {
        if(curr!=tail)
            curr=curr.Next();
      }

      @Override
      public int length() {
          return size;
      }

      @Override
      public int currPos() {
          Node<E>temp=head;
          int i;
          for(i=0;curr!=temp;i++)
              temp.Next();
          return i;

      }

      @Override
      public void moveToPos(int pos) {
        assert (pos>=0)&& (pos<=size):
          "Position out of Range";
        curr=head;
        for(int i=0;i<pos;i++)
            curr.Next();

      }

      @Override
      public E getValue() {
          if(curr.Next()==null)
              return null;
          return curr.Next().data();
      }

      @Override
     public String toString() {
          String result = "";
          Node current = head;
          while(current.Next() != null){
              result += current.data();
              if(current.Next() != null){
                  result += ", ";
              }
              current = current.Next();
          }
          return "" + result;
      }
}
```

This is the SequenceArr class which handles the operations on the array mentioned above (not complete here but all that is used in this example)

```
 public class SequenceArr {
 private TypeSeq [] SeqArr;
 private int size=0;
 private int MAXSIZE;

 public SequenceArr(int MAXSIZE){
     this.MAXSIZE=MAXSIZE;
     SeqArr =new TypeSeq[MAXSIZE];
     size=0;
 }
 public void insert(int pos, Type t, MyLinkedList<Character> seq){
     TypeSeq currentEl=new TypeSeq(t,seq);
     assert pos<=MAXSIZE: "Position over maximum size of array";
     SeqArr[size]=currentEl;
     size++;
    }
 public void remove(int pos){
     if(SeqArr[pos]!=null){
         while(SeqArr[pos+1]!=null){
             SeqArr[pos]=SeqArr[pos+1];
         }
         if(SeqArr[pos+1]==null){
             SeqArr[pos]=null;
         }
      }
     else
         System.out.print("No sequence to remove at specified position");
    }
 public void print(){
     int i=0;
     while (SeqArr[i]!=null){
         System.out.println(i+"\t"+SeqArr[i].getType()+"\t"+SeqArr[i].getBioSeq().toString());
         i++;
     }
    }
 public void print(int pos){
        if(SeqArr[pos]==null)
            System.out.print("No sequence to print at specified position");
        else
            System.out.println(SeqArr[pos].getType()+"\t"+SeqArr[pos].getBioSeq().toString());
    }
```

The custom data type i created that the array is made of

```
public class TypeSeq {
    private Type type;
    private MyLinkedList<Character> BioSeq;
    public TypeSeq(Type type, MyLinkedList<Character> BioSeq){
        this.type=type;
        this.BioSeq=BioSeq;
    }

    public MyLinkedList<Character> getBioSeq() {
        return BioSeq;
    }

    public void setBioSeq(MyLinkedList<Character> bioSeq) {
        BioSeq = bioSeq;
    }

    public Type getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(Type type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

and my DNAList class which handles input and contains the main method

```
    import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DNAList {
    static SequenceArr seqar;
    public static void main(String []args){
        MyLinkedList<String> hey=new MyLinkedList<>();
        hey.append("Hello");

        int arraysize= Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        String filePath=args[1];
        File file=new File(filePath);
        seqar=new SequenceArr(arraysize);
        exefromFile(file);

    }

    public static void exefromFile(File file){
        Scanner sc;
        try{
            sc=new Scanner(file);
            while(sc.hasNextLine()){
                String cmd=sc.nextLine();
                if(!cmd.equals(""))
                    execute(cmd);
            }


        }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }

    public static void execute(String s){
        s=s.trim();
        String [] commands=s.split("\\s+");
        switch (commands[0])
        {
            case "insert":
                int pos=Integer.parseInt(commands[1]);
                Type t=Type.fromString(commands[2]);
                char [] charArr=commands[3].toCharArray();
                MyLinkedList<Character> seq=new MyLinkedList<>(charArr.length);
                char curChar;
                for(int i=0;i<seq.length();i++){
                    curChar=charArr[i];
                    if(t==Type.DNA&&(curChar=='A'||curChar=='C'||curChar=='G'||curChar=='T'))
                        seq.append(charArr[i]);
                    else
                        System.out.print("Error occurred while inserting");
                }
                seqar.insert(pos,t,seq);
                break;
            case "remove":
                pos=Integer.parseInt(commands[1]);
                seqar.remove(pos);
                break;
            case "print":
                if(commands.length>1&&commands[1]!=null){
                    pos=Integer.parseInt(commands[1]);
                    seqar.print(pos);
                }
                else
                    seqar.print();
                break;
            case "clip":
                pos=Integer.parseInt(commands[1]);
                int start =Integer.parseInt(commands[2]);
                int end =Integer.parseInt(commands[3]);
                seqar.clip(pos,start,end);
                break;
            case "copy":
                int pos1=Integer.parseInt(commands[1]);
                int pos2=Integer.parseInt(commands[2]);
                seqar.copy(pos1,pos2);
                break;
            case "transcribe":
                pos=Integer.parseInt(commands[1]);
                seqar.transcribe(pos);
                break;
        }

    }

}
```

The input .txt file will say something like

insert 0 DNA AATTCCGGAATTCCGG

print

but the output will just be

0   DNA
and the sequence will not be printed. Any ideas?

Comment: In your TypeSeq class you are using "private Type type;" Which package does this Type class belong to? or is it a custom one?

Comment: Type belong to java.lang.reflect, however I'm not sure how you're getting this to compile because it can't find Type.fromString on my machine and I don't see this method referenced anywhere in the Java Type documentation.

Comment: Also you have not put the complete SequenceArr class

Comment: Then is this code not written by you?

Comment: Are you primarily interested in 1) learning how to implement linked lists, or 2)  storing DNA sequences in a list?   Because if #2, Java already provides excellent implementations of Lists of many kinds, including linked.  Just sayin'..

Comment: @HariPrasad type is a custom enum i created and I did write this code the SequenceArr class is not complete because it is very long and all the methods I cut out are not called here and I did not want to waste your time

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a lot of bugs in the code, to mention some:

```
MyLinkedList(int size){
    this();
}
MyLinkedList(){
    curr=tail=head=new Node<E>(null);
    size=0;
}
```

this always initialises your list with size 0.

```
char [] charArr=commands[3].toCharArray();
            MyLinkedList<Character> seq=new MyLinkedList<> 
(charArr.length);
```

I don't get the point of initialising your list with the size of 4 every-time. Also note, it's not going to initialise with the given size as you are always overriding it with 0.

```
@Override
  public void insert(E item) {
    curr.setNext(new Node<E>(item, curr.Next()));
    if(tail==curr)
        tail=curr.Next();
    size++;

  }
```

You are not utilising the concept of **head** at all, your first insert is a special case and needs to handled wisely.

```
 @Override
 public String toString() {
      String result = "";
      Node current = head;
      while(current.Next() != null){
          result += current.data();
          if(current.Next() != null){
              result += ", ";
          }
          current = current.Next();
      }
      return "" + result;
  }
```

head is always going to be null, when you print it's always going to result in first element being null. Moreover, when you find a node with it's next pointing to null, you should use its data. In your code, before returning the result you need to append the data from the last element too.

Comment: I understand all the bugs you're talking about and will fix them except the for one where the list is always initialized to 4. Where are you getting the 4 from it initializes to the length of the char array from the inputted txt file. Thanks for the help though!